# Deserialize JavaFX Color with Gson

Tags: java, javafx, gson

I am trying to serialize a `Color` with Gson and deserialize it also. The problem is, the deserialized type is a `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` instead of a `Color`.

Here is where I create the Gson object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapter(Color.class, new ColorGsonConverter()).create();
```

Here is my converter class:

```
public class ColorGsonConverter implements JsonSerializer<Color>, JsonDeserializer<Color> {
    @Override
    public Color deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        Log.debug("d"); // 'd' is not printed while deserializing
        JsonObject colorSave = arg0.getAsJsonObject();
        Color color = new Color(colorSave.get("red").getAsDouble(), colorSave.get("green").getAsDouble(), colorSave.get("blue").getAsDouble(), colorSave.get("opacity").getAsDouble());
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Color arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
        Log.debug("s"); // 's' is printed when serializing
        JsonObject colorSave = new JsonObject();
        colorSave.addProperty("red", arg0.getRed());
        colorSave.addProperty("green", arg0.getGreen());
        colorSave.addProperty("blue", arg0.getBlue());
        colorSave.addProperty("opacity", arg0.getOpacity());
        return arg2.serialize(colorSave);
    }
}
```

Here is the serialized version:

```
"appearance.derbydisplay.stoplightbordercolor": {
    "red": 1.0,
    "green": 1.0,
    "blue": 0.0,
    "opacity": 1.0
  }
```

Comment: `String json = gson.toJson(new Color(1, 1, 0, 0), Color.class); Color c = gson.fromJson(json, Color.class);` is working for me. Could you show a small program that reproduces your error?

Comment: I have been doing some digging, it appears that this is happening because I have a `Map<String, Property<?>>` that is storing `SimpleObjectProperty<Color>` and that is where it is causing problems. It doesn't know they type of the object, the String looks like a `Map` so it deserializes it as a `Map`. Weird so I think I will have to redesign my system.

Comment: I am now storing my `Color`s inside a bean instead of a `Map<String, Object>` it works now.